# Office 2016 pestering for Office 365 sign in details - how to remove O365 subscription/license?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, license, microsoft-office-2016

I have a corporate laptop that used to have O365 on. The license for it was yanked by the owner, so I installed a licensed copy of 2016 instead. The problem I now face is that both sets of details show up in the Account management pane of a particular office product, and the O365 won't sign in

- Add/remove programs shows only 2016 - it used to show "Office" with a blue icon and "Office 2016" with a red icon, the blue icon version was removed
- Each office app seems fully functional but gives a yellow banner "PRODUCT NOTICE There was a problem checking this device's license status. Please sign in with the office 365 account this device was activated with." [SIGN IN] (sign in cannot work; the details were changed by the owner)
- The version of winword.exe is 16.0.11328.20158, located at c:program files\Microsoft office\root\office16
- Launching WinWord.exe shows a splash banner containing "Office 365"
- The account page in the settings shows both licenses; the O365 has a button "Manage subscription", and the O2016 entry is licensed for all the same apps, and has a "Change License" button

Anyone know how/where to clear out the O365 related stuff?

Update: it's happening on another laptop here too, got some snips this time (the other laptop is out in the field)

Uninstall Programs cpl:

[image]

Account screen in an office product:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Please try this method:

1. Check your credential manager (<kbd>Start</kbd> > type in `credential manager` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)for entries related to the no-longer-used Office365 subscription. If you find any, delete them.
2. When this is done, make sure you are not signed in to Office 365 in Office programs (i.e. open Word and sign out using Account Options)
3. Run command prompt as admin (<kbd>Start</kbd> > type `cmd` > Right click > select "Run as administrator")
4. Type `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16`.

   If using 64-bit version of Office, go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16` instead.
5. Run `cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus`
6. Find the Office365 subscription in the list and record the last 5 characters of the license key `<key>`, i.e. `ABCDE`
7. Run `cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:<key>` (i.e. `cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:ABCDE` if your 5 characters were `ABCDE`)
8. Reboot your PC.
9. You may need to re-add your license key to Office if you removed the active license instead of the Office365 one by mistake.

Further reading / sources:

- https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/48973-remove-and-re-add-license-key-for-office-2016-on-office-365
- https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=47883

Comment: This no longer works in Version 1906.
 Can not find script file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ospp.vbs"